# Error Message: Implicit super constructor is undefind for default constructor

Tags: java, class

I'm looking for the cause of an error message "Implicit super constructor is undefind for default constructor......" and can't get any further. The red line is underlying the name of the class test01. The IDE is Visual Studio Code. Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

```
public class test01 {
}
void main(string args) {

    int zahl1, zahl2;
    CKunde Kunde1 = new CKunde(); 
    Cdaten d1 = new Cdaten();
    

}
```

}

Comment: In the code above your method `void main(string args)` is outside of your class body. A method has to belong to a class. The code above also has to many closing parenthesis `}` (3) compared to opening ones (2).  And on top of that your method signature for the main method is not correct.

Comment: Also: it should be `String` not `string`, because java is case sensitive. While I can't reproduce the error message you got with the amount of errors you have in those few lines I can only give you the recommendation to stop what you are doing and start from the very beginning with a basic java tutorial. Then work your way up from very basic programs.